# Return list of instances from generic method

Tags: common-lisp, evaluation, quote

I need to return a coordinate list of rectangle in generic method. Coordinate is a class 'cart' instance.

I try return it with make-instance

```lisp
(defclass line ()
  ((start :initarg :start :accessor line-start)
   (end   :initarg :end   :accessor line-end)))

(defmethod print-object ((lin line) stream)
  (format stream "[LINE ~s ~s]"
          (line-start lin) (line-end lin)))

(defclass cart ()
  ((x :initarg :x :reader cart-x)
   (y :initarg :y :reader cart-y)))

(defmethod print-object ((c cart) stream)
  (format stream "[CART x ~d y ~d]"
          (cart-x c) (cart-y c)))

(setq lin (make-instance 'line
             :start (make-instance 'cart :x 4 :y 3)
             :end (make-instance 'cart :x 7 :y 5)))

(defgeneric containing-rect (shape))

(defmethod containing-rect ((l line))
  (let ((x1 (cart-x (line-start l)))
        (y1 (cart-y (line-start l)))  
        (x2 (cart-x (line-end l)))
        (y2 (cart-y (line-end l))))
    (cond ((= x1 x2) 
           '((make-instance 'cart :x (1- x1) :y y1)
             (make-instance 'cart :x (1+ x1) :y y1)
             (make-instance 'cart :x (1- x2) :y y2)
             (make-instance 'cart :x (1+ x2) :y y2)))
          ((= y1 y2)
           '((make-instance 'cart :x x1 :y (1- y1))
             (make-instance 'cart :x x1 :y (1+ y1))
             (make-instance 'cart :x x2 :y (1- y2))
             (make-instance 'cart :x x2 :y (1+ y2))))
          (t 
           (rect '((make-instance 'cart :x x1 :y y1)
                   (make-instance 'cart :x x1 :y y2)
                   (make-instance 'cart :x x2 :y y2)
                   (make-instance 'cart :x x2 :y y1)))))))

(print (containing-rect lin))
```

I suppose `make-instance` should assign an instance to something

So i get incorrect result

```lisp
((MAKE-INSTANCE 'CART :X X1 :Y Y1) (MAKE-INSTANCE 'CART :X X1 :Y Y2)
 (MAKE-INSTANCE 'CART :X X2 :Y Y2) (MAKE-INSTANCE 'CART :X X2 :Y Y1))
```

but I need an output like that

```lisp
([CART x 4 y 3] [CART x 4 y 3] [CART x 4 y 3] [CART x 4 y 3])
```

Comment: Why not call the `lin` variables `line`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you `quote` something, it is not evaluated.

This:

```
'((make-instance 'cart :x (1- x1) :y y1)
  (make-instance 'cart :x (1+ x1) :y y1)
  (make-instance 'cart :x (1- x2) :y y2)
  (make-instance 'cart :x (1+ x2) :y y2))
```

is a *literal list* of four literal lists, each of which starts with the symbol `MAKE-INSTANCE`, then has a list `(QUOTE CART)`, etc.  This is exactly the result you see.

You seem to want to actually evaluate this.  The simplest thing would be to do that and make a list:

```
(list (make-instance 'cart :x (1- x1) :y y1)
      (make-instance 'cart :x (1+ x1) :y y1)
      (make-instance 'cart :x (1- x2) :y y2)
      (make-instance 'cart :x (1+ x2) :y y2))
```

This is a fundamentally different thing from quoting something.

Answer (score 3):

Some additional hints about your code.

#### Classes

Not a hard rule, but accessor functions (which are generic functions) are often only named after the slot, i.e. `x` and not `get-X` (definitely "bad" style) or `object-X` (*not bad*, still quite common).

```
(defclass line ()
 ((start :initarg :start :accessor start)
  (end   :initarg :end   :accessor end)))

(defclass cart ()
 ((x :initarg :x :reader x)
  (y :initarg :y :reader y)))

(defclass rect ()
  ((upper-left :initarg :upper-left :accessor upper-left)
   (bootom-right :initarg :bottom-right :accessor bottom-right)))
```

I don't know what your requirements are, so I invented some; in particular, I represent rectangles as 2 points (upper-left and bottom-right).

#### Constructor functions

Having constructor functions helps a lot to have concise and readable code:

```
(defun cart (x y) 
  (make-instance 'cart :x x :y y))

(defun line (start end) 
  (make-instance 'line :start start :end end))
```

In the case of  rectangles, points are sorted first in order to build the upper-left and bottom-right points.

```
(defun sorted-coordinate (points coordinate)
  (sort (mapcar coordinate points) #'<))

(defun rect (point-1 point-2)
  (let ((points (list point-1 point-2)))
    (destructuring-bind (low-x high-x) (sorted-coordinate points #'x)
      (destructuring-bind (low-y high-y) (sorted-coordinate points #'y)
        (make-instance 'rect
                       :upper-left (cart low-x high-y)
                       :bottom-right (cart high-x low-y))))))
```

#### Printer methods

Your code *almost* printed Lisp forms, and for no added complexity, you can in fact make the printer method emit code that can be read back to build the same data. The following methods print *readably* your objects with `PRIN1`, as calls to the previously defined constructor functions:

```
(defmethod print-object ((line line) stream)
  (prin1 `(line ,(start line) ,(end line)) stream))

(defmethod print-object ((c cart) stream)
  (prin1 `(cart ,(x c) ,(y c)) stream))

(defmethod print-object ((rect rect) stream)
  (prin1 `(rect ,(upper-left rect) ,(bottom-right rect)) stream))
```

#### Example

```
(defparameter *test-line*
  (line (cart 4 3) (cart 7 5)))
```

Then, evaluating the resulting line gives:

```
CL-USER> *TEST-LINE*
=> (LINE (CART 4 3) (CART 7 5))
```

This above is a value, as printed by the REPL, which is exactly the expression that was used to build it.

#### Boundary of a shape as a rectangle

The generic function is much simpler (but maybe wrong, since rectangles are handled differently):

```
(defgeneric containing-rect (shape))

(defmethod containing-rect ((line line))
  (rect (start line) (end line)))
```

For example:

```
CL-USER> (containing-rect *test-line*)
=> (RECT (CART 4 5) (CART 7 3))
```